# exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am getting a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` error message when
`INSERT INTO database`.

I am using: Python 2.7.5, Scrapy 0.18 and database MySQL

My Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 781, in __bootstrap
        self.__bootstrap_inner()
      File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 761, in run self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\threadpool.py", line 191, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\enterprise\adbapi.py", line 448, in _runInteraction
        result = interaction(trans, *args, **kw)

      File "apple\pipelines.py", line 49, in _conditional_insert

        'INSERT INTO job (id, company, day, hour, job, car1, car2) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ("company, day, hour, job, car1, car2 ")

exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is my code script:

```
def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    # create record if doesn't exist. 
    # all this block run on it's own thread
    tx.execute('select * from job where hour = %s', ("item['hour'], "))
    result = tx.fetchone()
    if result:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:
        tx.execute(\
            'INSERT INTO job (id, company, day, hour, job, car1, car2) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ("company, day, hour, job, car1, car2 ")
        )
        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

def handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)
```

Any idea what I can do to get across that error?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `%` in the following line. Also, I assume that the value come from the `item` argument.

```
'INSERT INTO job (id, company, day, hour, job, car1, car2) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' ("company, day, hour, job, car1, car2 ")
```

Should be

```
'INSERT INTO job (id, company, day, hour, job, car1, car2) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' % (item['company'], item['day'], item['hour'], item['job'], item['car1'], item['car2'])
```

You can also use the `format` method from string:

```
'INSERT INTO job (id, company, day, hour, job, car1, car2) values ({company}, {day}, {hour}, {job}, {car1}, {car2})'.format(**item)
```

By the way, the following line probably does not do what you expect:

```
tx.execute('select * from job where hour = %s', ("item['hour'], "))
```

it should read

```
tx.execute('select * from job where hour = %s' % item['hour'])
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I receive another error: exceptions.TypeError: not enough arguments for format string. someone can tell me how can I solve?                                       Where I must add parentheses?

Comment: See my updated answer. You might want to brush up on [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html)

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate your help. Another error is, but I don't know resolve. An ideea for my help. Thanks in advance. 
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[u'TT']' at line 1")

Comment: @paul t. Thanks for help. I implemented your code, receive error:

   ** return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 29, in from_se
ttings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 38, in load_ob
ject
    mod = __import__(module, {}, {}, [''])
  File "apple\pipelines.py", line 43
    tx.execute('select * from job where hour = %s', (item["hour"], ))
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block**

Comment: @Floriano, weird, it's the first indented line after the `def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):`

Comment: @paul t. What can I do?

Comment: @Floriano, can you post your code to pastebin or gist.github for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I think OP's intention was to use placeholders and parameters as tuple.

The code should then look like:

```
def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    # create record if doesn't exist. 
    # all this block run on it's own thread
    tx.execute('select * from job where hour = %s', (item["hour"], ))
    result = tx.fetchone()
    if result:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:
        tx.execute(
            'INSERT INTO job (company, day, hour, job, car1, car2) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
            (item["company"], item["day"], item["hour"], item["job"], item["car1"], item["car2"])
        )
        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

def handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)
```

I removed the `id` column in  'INSERT INTO job (id, company,...'